# How to run operations with lower precedence in C before ones with higher precedence

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int a,b;
    a=1;
    b=1;
    if ( (a | 65534)&1 == (b | 65534)&1 )
    {
      printf("The rightmost bit is the same");  
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The rightmost bit is different");
    }
    return 0;
}


}
```

Output:
The rightmost bit is different

Expected:
The rightmost bit is the same

Here the "==" is run before "&" which is not desirable. I can take another variable to fix this but not taking another variable is sort of the point of this assignment...

Comment: `((a & 65534) & 1) == ((b & 65534) & 1)`

Comment: Isn't this the entire purpose of parentheses?

Comment: `(x & 65534) & 1` is always `0`

Comment: Given what you are printing, the expected test would be `if ((a & 1) == (b & 1))`  Why are you throwing 65534 into the mix?

Comment: Odd that you have parentheses where they aren't needed, yet don't have them where they are needed. So I think the correct answer to this exercise is to move the parentheses: `if ( (a & 65534 & 1) == (b & 65534 & 1) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more parenthesis:

```
if ( ((a & 65534)&1) == ((b & 65534)&1) )
```